# What is an effective method for reducing heat from a bitumen roll roof?

Tags: insulation, roof, roofing, heat

I have simple bitumen roll roof with additional insulation, no air pocket space, no nothing and heats up a lot in summer.

I have been considering either heat reflective paint or installing solar panels. My research so far, suggests that reflective paint may not adhere properly or peel off in few years, while the solar panels get heated themselves and it's unclear if they would be of any help or actually worsen the situation, even with air space between them and the roof. With no prior experience, I am lost.

What are the most efficient methods for heat protection (not confined to the above mentioned ones), disregarding cost and installation complexity for the time being?

Comment: Recommendations are opinion based and opinion based questions are off-topic here. Please [edit] to ask what are the pros/cons of Option A, Option B, and an Option C I haven't thought of yet, and you'll be right on topic

Comment: Solar panels should have an air space between them and the roof, giving somewhat cooling ventilation.  Depending on what you use, probably other bonuses, but expensive still they pay back their cost.

Comment: @ FreeMan - did some edits, how does it sound now?

Comment: It heats up more from the sun hitting it.  Shade to stop the sun will drop the temperature quite a bit, if shade will pay for itself is a bonus.  Reflexive paint should drop the temperature also, but might need to be re-apply and should get some cost saving from a cooler roof.  Depending on location, solar panels should have some rebates plus give shade plus provide electricity or hot water.

Comment: Crip659 put your 2 comments into an answer and I will upvote, you hit both, I agree with paint and it can last 10 years depending on the area but it will need repainting. Or  EPDM can last 20+

Comment: A negative result comment: my former workplace had a concrete roof which was covered in black rubber stuff. Extremely hot in the room. My boss had the roof silver-painted, did not help much at all, still blazing in the room, and had to be redone every couple years. For long-term, I'd say reflective paint is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the solar panels, they are designed to be in the sun and the shade they afford your roof will make a big difference. Adding reflective paint would help as well, the most common one I am familiar with is silver in color. To bad you cannot let air pass under the roof.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried yet, but recommended by a roof specialist: roof vents to allow dissipation of the overheated air inside the room. He said the shadow from solar panels might help, as well, but roof vents cost really nothing in comparison.